# Excel area chart - y axis and major grid does not match 1 of the 2 series values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Using an area chart to show survey responses as two series with four data points in each. The x-axis are the four answer choices, the y axis is the percentage of respondents.

The problem is the data on the second series is graphically exaggerated, the largest data point is 75% (reflected in the labels if I turn them on) but looking at the y axis and corresponding gridlines, it is charted as around 125%. that is only for the second of the 2 series, that first is accurate.

Comment: Have you checked each axis min/max values? Likely they're different, causing the discrepancy. Go into their format sections and set each manually-don't keep the auto setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a Stacked Area Chart. Change the chart type to "Area Chart"

[image]

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should probably use a line chart rather than an area chart.